# How to calculate the needed order of a LPF?

Tags: analog, filter, passive-components

I am new to filters and am asked to calculated a lot of things for a passive (Butterworth and Chebyshev )LPF. The very first thing asked is to determine the needed order LPF for these specifications:

[image]

How can I determine what order I need fot these specifiaction? With which formula?

Comment: I guess it's good that you didn't even try to hide that this is a homework question, but no one will or should help you unless you add what you think you should do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Agreed... better paste your entire homework. But look at the Matlab Filter Design packages.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, the maximum allowed ripple in the pass band is 0.1 dB. This is compatible with Chebyshev filters. Tabulated values for Butterworth responses are based on a maximum damping variation of 3dB within the pass band. 
There is a formula which gives the minimum required Chebyshev filter order based on the damping requirements (as given in your diagram) and the ratio of the relevant frequencies (end of passband and begin of the stop band).
Did you start already a search for such a formula? Can be found in relevant filter books and Internet contributions.